# MySQL LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE

Tags: mysql, xml, load, local, load-data-infile

I'm building an application on my local machine, and for the longest time, was using Windows 7 with MySQL installed, but as I've now moved onto Linux, I'm trying to execute this statement:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'http://example.com/tech.xml'

INTO TABLE t

ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<product>';
```

This is not working, and I do have all the privileges necessary in order to accomplish this.

How can I make this statement work?

When I was using Windows (r) the statement would work perfectly. Where do I put the file on my web server if I want to access it via MySQL?

I get this error:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that          
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
syntax to use near 'XML LOCAL INFILE 'http://example.com/tech.xml'

INTO TABLE t

ROWS IDENTIFIE' at line 1
```

Comment: Please *never* only say "this is not working". Please *always* describe what error comes back, and quote the exact error message. Thanks!

Comment: Check the edit. For Windows (r), I was using 'c:/users/name/desktop/tech.xml'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`LOAD XML INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html) is available from mySQL 5.2 and higher.

You probably have an older version than that.